# How can I multiboot Windows XP, Ubuntu 12.04, Windows 7 and Pardus 2011?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows, syslinux

Is it possible to install Windows XP with Ubuntu 12.04 on master drive. And Windows 7 with Pardus 2011 on slave drive?

If so, can you provide instructions on how to go about doing so? I had to wipe both my drives because the MBR got screwed up somehow. I tried fixing, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the going gets rough partition-wise (independent of your OS) you may want to turn to [Terabyte Unlimited](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/index.htm) with its excellent products and near-immediate support. [BootIt](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/index.htm) allows you to boot up to 200 (!) primary (!) partitions.

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated etc, just a long-time happy customer of theirs. Good luck!

Comment: That looks like a great software nutty. But I was wondering if "GRUB 2" was able to pull this off, and if somebody knew how to pull this off. Also Terabyte cost $$$. No biggie, but why pay if it could be done for free. Peace. And Thank You.

Comment: Sure, I too would be curious to see a corresponding conventional partition table (incl. a shared SWAP partition?) for GRUB. - Still, just one more word on TBI and Bootit: I think I paid like 50 $ at the time for the bundle and a lifetime licence, incl. support... IMHO it's massively underpriced and undervalued. And I'm HAPPY to pay for good and reliable software (and/or support); not all programmers manage to survive "non-profit" and on "thin air". They too need to eat sth and sleep somewhere...

Comment: ...and w.r.t. fixing a screwed MBR: again, it's Terabyte Unlimited who've made some IT-experts (check experts-exchange.com for instance) scream for joy after days of tears and despair... btw, I came about it after Acronis (another $$$) produced a backup-restore which wouldn't boot...